# Strange behavior of -exec in find command

Tags: bash

In a bash shell under Linux and find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2, I write:

```
touch FOO
find . -name FOO -exec echo {} `echo ./FOO {} | tr [A-Z] [a-z]` \;
```

And I get

```
./FOO ./foo ./FOO
```

Why is the output different from ./FOO ./foo ./foo?

Narrowing the problem:

```
find . -name FOO -exec echo `echo {} | tr [A-Z] [a-z]` \;
```

yields `"./FOO"` instead of `"./foo"`

I am quite puzzled by this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell executes the command between back-ticks before it launches `find` at all.

Thus, the `find` command that's actually executed for your first command line is:

```
find . -name FOO -exec echo {} ./foo {} \;
```

That should give you the output you are seeing:

```
./FOO ./foo ./FOO
```

The second command also executes the command between back-ticks first, so the `find` command that's actually executed for the second command line is:

```
find . -name FOO -exec echo {} \;
```

which should, and does, echo `./FOO`.

Answer (score 1):

Command substitution is performed *before* the `find` command is executed. This means your initial command

```
find . -name FOO -exec echo {} `echo ./FOO {} | tr [A-Z] [a-z]` \;
```

actually becomes

```
find . -name FOO -exec echo {} ./foo {} \;
```

which results in

```
./FOO ./foo ./FOO
```

If you want to execute arbitrary shell code on the results of your find, invoke a shell:

```
find -name FOO -exec bash -c 'echo "$1" | tr [A-Z] [a-z]' -- {} \;
```

(Note that if searching in the current directory, the `.` is unnecessary)

Of course, if all you're doing is converting to lowercase, it would be better to do it like this:

```
find -name FOO | tr [A-Z] [a-z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your -exec syntax is wrong. Use this:

```
find . -name FOO -exec bash -c "echo -n {}; echo ' ./FOO' {} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'" \;
./FOO ./foo ./foo
```